# SetSchemaMetadata for both key and value

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using the Kafka Connect JDBC Source Connector to stream data from a Postgres Database to Kafka. All messages in the kafka cluster are Avro messages managed by the Schema Registry.
I want to set explicitly the schema name for both the key and value of the messages.

I managed to do it for either the key or the value by using the `SetSchemaMetadata` option on the config.

For setting the schema name for the value, I am using:

```
"transforms": "SetSchemaMetadata",
"transforms.SetSchemaMetadata.type": 
"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.SetSchemaMetadata$Value",
"transforms.SetSchemaMetadata.schema.name": "myCustomValueSchemaName"
```

For the key, I am using :

```
"transforms": "SetSchemaMetadata",
"transforms.SetSchemaMetadata.type": 
"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.SetSchemaMetadata$Key",
"transforms.SetSchemaMetadata.schema.name": "myCustomKeySchemaName"
```

Is there a way to set both of them on the connect config ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use chained tranformation:

```
"transforms": "KeySchemaMetadata,ValueSchemaMetadata",

"transforms.KeySchemaMetadata.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.SetSchemaMetadata$Key",
"transforms.KeySchemaMetadata.schema.name": "myCustomKeySchemaName",

"transforms.ValueSchemaMetadata.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.SetSchemaMetadata$Value",
"transforms.ValueSchemaMetadata.schema.name": "myCustomValueSchemaName"
```

Comment: Many thanks :) Did not know we can chain operators !